# how to output console.log in url

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

this

```
fs = require('fs');
var data = fs.readFileSync('./number/data', 'utf8');
console.log(data)
```

i can change to this

```
await page.goto('https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=console.log(data);text=kaka');
```

Comment: that's not possible my friend;

Comment: is there any other more perfect way to show files in url?

Comment: in backend you can only read `querystring` , not modify them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to output the contents of data into the URL? If yes then use string interpolation.

```js
await page.goto(`https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=${data};text=kaka`);
```

Comment: You are welcome. Notice that the string is created with backtick character ( ` ) and not quote. Did this solve your problem? if yes, please mark it as the answer, thank you.